# Number of nodes with degree d in a graph

Tags: graph-theory

Why the number of nodes with degree $d$ in a graph $G$ is equal to the number of copies of $d$-stars in $G$ that are not part of any $(d + 1)$ star in $G$ ?

Isn't it possible to have nodes with degree $d$ which don't belong to a $d$-star?

Let's think to a node with degree $d$ that seems to be the center of a star, but at least one couple of the fake star's vertices is connected and indeed it is not the center of a star....

For me a $d$ star is a subgraph of $d+1$ vertices and $d$ edges where there exists only edges from the center to the vertices, but not edges between vertices within a star. Other edges such the ones between vertices of different stars are allowed to exist.

Comment: I don't believe that your notion of a d star is correct. Instead, think of a d star as an analog of a ball or radius 1, where each edge is assigned a distance of one. Then the star about a vertex is all vertices of distance 1 about the vertex and edges between them.  I'm pretty sure this is the standard idea.

Comment: I think if you consider induced subgraphs, then you are correct.  But here I guess the "copies of $d$-stars" refer to subgraphs (not necessarely induced).  So here a d-star is a set of $d+1$ vertices such that there is a center $v$ that is a neighbor of every other vertex in the set.  That's it - we don't care if there are other edges, as long as this condition holds it's a d-star.